# Installing Notifee with Expo: Error: Notifee native module not found

Tags: react-native, plugins, linker, expo, react-native-native-module

I'm trying to install Notifee with Expo by using the steps on the installation page: `expo install @notifee/react-native` and followed by adding `"@notifee/react-native"` to my plugins in my app.json file then running `expo prebuild` but I'm still getting errors `Error: Notifee native module not found.` and `Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.` I manually added the `"plugins": []` to my app.json. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Here's what my app.json looks like:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "GymTracker",
    "slug": "GymTracker",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "GymTracker.app"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": ["@notifee/react-native"]
  }
}
```

and my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Error: Notifee native module not found` is clear. You are trying to use native modules in Expo Go client App which not registered and compiled.

Notifee requires Native modules which do not work with The Expo Go client app. You need to compile your custom Expo Go Dev Client with Notifee pre-embedded.

Follow instruction here to compile custom Expo Dev client _ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id0Im72UN6w